# Exporting raster identifiers to table when running ArcGIS ExtractValuesToTable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.8

I am running the ArcGIS 10.8 Geostatistical analyst ExtractValuesToTable tool to extract values from multiple rasters at input points. The tool completes successfully, but it is not possible to tie the results back to each individual raster. The SrcID_Rast column contains the value 0 for all extracted rasters:

[image: screenshot showing only 0s in the SrcID_Rast column of the resulting table]

How can I ensure that the names of each raster are included in the table so that I can link the extracted values to the correct source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to address this issue by including the optional `out_raster_names_table` argument, per the documentation of the [Extract Values to Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/geostatistical-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-table.htm) tool. When a file path is provided to for this argument, the `SrcID_Rast` field is populated with an integer and the corresponding raster names are exported to a separate table:

`out_table` result

[image]

`out_raster_names_table` result
[image]
(Raster names not show).